# Detecting when Y is a vowel

Tags: rust

While learning the programming language Rust, I want to make a numerology calculator based on a person's full name.  This numerology calculator would, later on, provide computations on other pieces of texts as well as other numbers.

The numerology calculator would take a name such as John Edward Smith and calculate his life path like this, for example:

```
    1 + 6 + 8 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 5 + 1 + 9  + 4  +  1  + 4 + 9 + 2 + 8
    J   O   H   N   E   D   W   A   R    D     S    M   I   T   H
```

Adding up all the letters yields 71 and 7+1 = 8

Another calculation uses the vowels in the name, and here is the problem: most algorithms detect whether a letter in question is AEIO or U and declares it to be a vowel. Otherwise, it's a consonant.  However, Y could be either a vowel or a consonant.  W is also sometimes a vowel but for the purposes of numerology, it is always a consonant.

I came across a cargo package called Eudex (supposedly better than Soundex) but I don't know how to use it to detect whether Y is a vowel or consonant.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

```
fn main() {
    assert!((Hash::new("jumpo") - Hash::new("jumbo")).similar());
    assert!(!(Hash::new("Horse") - Hash::new("Norse")).similar());
    println!("{:?}", Hash::new("hello"));
    println!(Hash::new("Sydney")).listVowels());
} 

Hash { hash: 144115188075855872 }
```

Fantasy result of the last print line:
ye

Comment: I'm neither an expert on rust nor numerology, however, it may help others to help you if you can explain the rules that would determine whether the letter "y" is a vowel or not.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/why-y-is-sometimes-a-vowel-usage

Comment: The Eudex crate is not intended for this kind of thing. It can only tell you when words are phonetically "similar", but can't tell you why.

Comment: Why not just turn the rules from the Merriam Webster link into a method that applies them?

Comment: Something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=baf01eb3b1bd9e874fa91e89158d19c1

Comment: That is along the lines of what I am looking for.  However, this fails: assert_eq!(vec![true,  false, true, false, false, true], vowels("Yvonne"));  Just need to divide the word into syllables.

Comment: http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/Syllables.htm has a dictionary of syllables.